# Discord Bot won't reply

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've being doing discord.js bot development for about 5 days, but not ever started over like I am now. I set up everything, and wanted to test if my bot was working so I added the command but for some reason the bot doesn't reply / run the code. It doesn't give an error even though the bots also online, does anyone know the solution?

```
const { info } = require("console");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { Permissions } = require("discord.js");
const { cp } = require("fs");

const prefix = "."

require("fs");
require("dotenv").config();

const client = new Discord.Client({intents : ["GUILDS", "DIRECT_MESSAGES", "GUILD_BANS", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_PRESENCES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"]});

const embedColor = 0X2B78FF;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("ready");
})

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'hello') {
        await message.channel.send("hi")
    }
})

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Zsolt commented already, you have every Intent that you would need generally there but you are missing one "essential" intent, and that is `GUILD_MESSAGES`, so for clarity. Your bot does not "see" your message. Adding that to your `const client = new Discord.Client({intents : []})` will fix the issue.

Also keep in mind that in [Discord's Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), there are intents aswell. They introduced new intent not long ago, so you should check that too to avoid issues in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That work for me and should do for yours aswell:

```
global.Discord = require('discord.js')
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS], partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that type of `Intents` is deprecated, you need `GatewayIntentBits`.

Secondly, The bot needs (I have no idea why, you have to see documentation) the `MessageContent` intent.

Thirdly, as said above, you don't have the `GuildMessages` intent (hope I don't annoy you with that said from 2 other people).

(TIP: the Intents above are in the `GatewayIntentBit` syntax, so you can copypaste without any danger)

And here a snippet of my code that *should* work:

```
    const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Client({ intents: [
            GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
            GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
            GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping,
        ],
     });
```

`Guilds` = `GUILDS`

`MessageContent` = *you need to read **and** send messages*

`DirectMessageTyping` = `DIRECT_MESSAGES`

here documentation: https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits